# Is there a way to inherit the parent __init__ arguments?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-typing

Suppose I have a basic class inheritance:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, filepath: str, debug=False):
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.debug = debug

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, portnumber: int, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.portnumber = portnumber
```

For typing and completion purposes, I would like to somehow "forward" the list of arguments from `A.__init__()` to `B.__init__()`.

Is there a way to do this? To have a type checker correctly infer the signature for `B.__init__(...)` and have an IDE be able to provide meaningful completions or checks?

---

[edit] after searching a little bit more, here is something that is perhaps closer to what I look:

if I declared `A` and `B` as *dataclasses* :

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    filepath: str
    debug: bool = False

@dataclass
class B(A):
    portnumber: int = 42
```

I can get the following hints in vscode with the standard pylance extension:
[image: screen capture of vscode autocompletion]

Could there be something similar to target just the `__init__()` method?
perhaps by explicitly naming the base method that gets "extended" (e.g: a special `@extends(A.__init__)` decorator)?

Comment: Probably not without a lot of boilerplate. Python idioms aren't always well supported by static type checking. Remember, the key point of `super` is that you *don't* know statically what values `kwargs` might get, because that depends on the dynamic/runtime type of `self`, not any static properties of `A` or `B`.

Comment: Do you have any reason for not doing it explicitely: `class B(A):
    def __init__(self, portnumber: int, filepath: str, debug=False):...`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta That's not considered idiomatic Python.

Comment: Imagine a diamond inheritance case with `class C(A): ...` and `class D(C, B): ...`. `D.__init__` will accept arguments for `C` which need to go through `B.__init__` first, and `B` cannot anticipate what the types of those arguments might be.

Comment: @chepner: I can understand that. When I first learned Python, I was told that compile time (i.e. static) type checking was not a Python thing. Yet the typing module was created to allow static type checking. IMHO there is a balance between sticking to idiomatic Python and allowing most efficient static checks. And the *correct* balance point may depend on team usages, etc. Provided everything is explicit and documented of course...

Comment: `B` is violating the LSP. `A` might be called with a signature like `A('./bar', True)` which `B` doesn't accept.

Comment: @InSync `__init__` falls in a gray area. LSP requires that an *instance* of `B` be usable anywhere an instance of `A` is expected, but in practice you are very rarely writing code like `for x in some_as_and_bs: x.__init__(...)`. The standard advice for `super` and `__init__` (only use keyword arguments) sidesteps the issue rather well: accept arbitrary keyword arguments, but only pass on the ones you didn't define as parameters yourself.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: I can do it on a one of basis, I was looking for a way to not have to manually audit all the inheritence chains to forward updates to descendant classes

Comment: @LeGEC: then you should follow chepner's advice...

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible, but personally I wouldn't recommend it - see below:

```py
from typing import TypedDict, Unpack

class AInterface(TypedDict):
    filepath: str
    debug: bool

class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Unpack[AInterface]):
        self.filepath = kwargs["filepath"]
        self.debug = kwargs["debug"]

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, portnumber: int, **kwargs: Unpack[AInterface]):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.portnumber = portnumber
```

By using the `TypedDict` we can structure the kwargs argument giving it a type, and allowing us to pass it through. If you have multiple inheritance you could even combine the interfaces together to produce the current kwargs type. When you use the `__init__` for A and B you still get warned if you miss parts of the `TypedDict`.

I would instead just pass the arguments down to the next layer manually:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, filepath: str, debug: bool =False):
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.debug = debug

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, portnumber: int, filepath: str, debug: bool =False):
        super().__init__(filepath=filepath, debug = debug)
        self.portnumber = portnumber
```

Comment: Worth nothing that the `Unpack` approach assumes a closed inheritance hierarchy, where you can assume that `A.__init__` doesn't itself need to use `super().__init__` (because it would just be a call to the do-nothing `object.__init__) and that `B.__init__` will *only* be calling `A.__init__` via `super`.

Comment: (If that's a valid assumption, I would go with `Unpack` over manually duplicating the parameters. If it's not, then hard-coding the parameters doesn't work.)

Comment: I would note also that `A.__init__` can still define `file path` and `debug` as explicit parameters, rather than having to extract them from `kwargs`; only `B` has to use `Unpack[AInterface]` to ensure `**kwargs` is properly typed for the call to `super().__init__`.

Comment: @chepner re `filepath` and `debug` being explicit parameters - that's true, although that part was actually by design - if you define the parameters in both AInterface and A.__init__ then it takes away the point of separating it out, as you still have the parameters in two places (just two different places). If both of them use the same interface there is at least a single source of truth for where the parameters are stored.

Comment: Ok, that's valid, so far as it goes :) (But if it does change, you still need to change the body of `__init__`, just not the signature.)

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a bad idea: it's not clear, why you want to have 2 classes with almost similar fields that have similar methods. you can probably just have the `class B` and set `portnumber` to `None` and check it inside methods.

generally, it's a bad idea to use inheritance, unless you are forced by a framework or a supervisor, especially if your classes are as simple as in your example.